# Scenekit rotate fill material direction

Tags: core-graphics, scenekit

I fill material to geometry. And setup material scale to fill this geometry like following code:

```
materal.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(width,height,0);
materal.diffuse.wrapS = SCNWrapModeRepeat;
materal.diffuse.wrapT = SCNWrapModeRepeat;
```

the problem is material is filled from top -> bottom direction.

How can I make material scale and repeat from bottom to top. 
any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

try many solution and following trick work for me

```
materal.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4Translate(SCNMatrix4MakeScale(length, height, 0), 0, ceil(height) - height, 0);
```